# FlexJSON doesn't serialize class objects fully

Tags: java, json, flexjson

I am new to FlexJson and was following http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/ for simple tutorial.
I wrote a simple program but it seems not to be serializing the object attributes. Please help me if someone knows about this

```
package com.webapp.enter;

import flexjson.JSONSerializer;

class PObject {

       String name;
       int age;
       String country;

        public PObject (String n, int a , String c){
            this.name = n;
            this.country = c;
            this.age = a;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return this.name + this.age + this.country;
        }

        public String[] getData(){
            return new String[]{ this.name, this.country};
        }
}

public class Person{

    public static void main(String main[]){
        PObject person = new PObject("harit",23,"india");
        System.out.println(person.name +  " - " + person.age + " - " + person.country);

        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        String out = serializer.serialize(person);
        System.out.println("S : " + out);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
compile-single:
run-main:
harit - 23 - india
S : {"class":"com.webapp.enter.PObject"}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**(Update from deleted answer):**

I tried to modify the code using getter/setter methods, now it fails saying the following. I apologize if I am doing it wrong, I am new to this

```
package com.webapp.enter;

import flexjson.JSONSerializer;

class PObject {

       String name;
       int age;
       String country;

        public PObject (){

        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setAge(int age){
            this.age = age;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country){
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public int getAge(){
            return this.age;
        }

        public String getCountry(){
            return this.country;
        }

}

public class Person{

    public static void main(String main[]){
        PObject person = new PObject();
        person.setAge(23);
        person.setCountry("usa");
        person.setName("test");
        System.out.println(person.name +  " - " + person.age + " - " + person.country);

        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        String out = serializer.serialize(person);
        System.out.println("S : " + out);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
test - 23 - usa
Exception in thread "main" flexjson.JSONException: Error trying to deepSerialize
        at flexjson.transformer.ObjectTransformer.transform(ObjectTransformer.java:97)
        at flexjson.transformer.TransformerWrapper.transform(TransformerWrapper.java:22)
        at flexjson.JSONContext.transform(JSONContext.java:75)
        at flexjson.JSONSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializer.java:378)
        at flexjson.JSONSerializer.deepSerialize(JSONSerializer.java:301)
        at com.webapp.enter.Person.main(Person.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class flexjson.transformer.ObjectTransformer can not access a member of class com.webapp.enter.PObject with modifiers "public"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at flexjson.transformer.ObjectTransformer.transform(ObjectTransformer.java:45)
        ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 10):

Flexjson works off Java Beans and PObject does not follow the Java Bean specification.  You either need to add getters for your properties: name, age, and country, or you need mark those fields public.  Either one will work.  Add setters if you plan on using JSONDeserializer to deserialize your object.

Comment: Hi,chubbsondubs,I had a similar problem.Does it affect if your getter and setters are private or your constructor is private?

Comment: Can you also please give a good link for Java Bean Specification.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can mark the getter/setter either private or protected and Flexjson will pick it up.  Same goes for the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this made me realize one of my setters were incorrectly names.

Comment: We are facing this problem even when all getter/setters are correctly named.

Comment: @SPS Can you post an example of your object that you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring 3 or above then you have to remove the entry like

map.remove("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.string");

from model map just before the serialization. It works like a charm. It is better you do it in the view component where you are implementing the view.
Have a look at following code.

```
public class JsonView implements View{

@Override
public String getContentType() {
    return "application/json";
}

@Override
public void render(Map<String, ?> map, HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    map.remove("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.string");
    final String data = new JSONSerializer().deepSerialize(map);

    response.getWriter().write(data);
}
```

}